# Is it possible to define inverse cascadeType.ALL on @ManyToOne side?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, cascade

Let's say I have child entity and parent entity. Parent can have many children. But I do not want to map child entity in Parent entity class. In other words I do not want to have @OneToMany field in parent class. I want it to be hibernate unidirectional relation defined in child entity using @ManyToOne annotation.

Is it possible to somehow defined "inverse" cascadeType.ALL which will delete all children entity of parent upon parent deletion without creating @OneToMany field in parent class?

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: If your relation is uni-directional, why don't you just delete all children with the parent entities' FK with a query?

Comment: @PaulDaechert Yes that is possible but I was curious if there does not exist any way using annotations or some configuration.

Comment: I don't see how this can be possible if you do not want to have a list of children in the parent. After all the annotation will also just generate query statements, so it's not very different, possibly even less efficient than doing it *by hand*